# WIndows 8 system file checker

Tags: windows-8

I am having a few issues with Windows 8 regarding OS operating system files. I ran `SFC /scannow` and was looking at the CBS.LOG file.  I am wondering where I can help in determining the issues noted in the log file. Here is an example of one of the issues reported:

> ****2013-10-17 16:20:23, Info                  CSI    00000081 Ignoring duplicate ownership for directory [l:92{46}]"\??\C:\ProgramData\regid.1991-06.com.microsoft" in component Microsoft-Windows-Branding-Base-Core, Version = 6.2.9200.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
>
> 2013-10-17 16:20:23, Info                  CSI    00000082 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:64{32}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\Bthprops" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-BTH-CPL, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral****

SFC indicated that repairs could not be made.

Comment: So, what issues are you having exactly? I mean why did you run `sfc /scannow` in the first place?

Comment: I am having issues with the metro tiles and tried all other indicated means to fix. MS support told me to run SFC to repair any corrupt files. MS support also said that I can use the windows 8 CD just to replace the OS and assured me that none of my programs and files would be affected.  I am really trying to do all I can without reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 8 there is a better tool included. It is called DISM, which was created in Windows 7, but [it was updated in Windows 8](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx).

Here run the command `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to detect and repair corrupted files. DISM also download corrupted files, which sfc doesn't do.

Comment: thanks so much!  I will give this a go. Just wondering if there is anything I should look out for? As this is my primary work laptop, I am just being overly cautious!

Comment: in the **DISM.log** you can later see if the tool repaired anything or not.

Comment: Where do I find this log file?

Comment: here: "C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log". Search for entries after **Checking System Update Readiness**