# Windows 10 Fall Creators Update with unsigned mmc.exe

Tags: windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709, mmc

After upgrading to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Version: 1709, OS Build: 16299.64) mmc.exe is not recognized as a signed file.

1. I tried to execute it from cmd as administrator and worked:

   c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe c:\Windows\System32\services.msc
2. When I'm trying to start the Services app (that is using mmc.exe).
   [image]

   I get the following error

   [image]

The file indeed looks like unsigned (but I didn't checked on previous releases). Comparatively other executable file has the tab Digital Signature.

[image]

3. I tried to fix everything by running with no success:

   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   sfc /scannow

There is any solution to fix this?

Comment: The file properties indicate you have 16299.15 installed but not the build you think is installed

Comment: “I tried to execute it from cmd as administrator and worked:“ So it worked or didn’t work?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/uac-unknown-publisher-alert-with-microsoft/2d787ac4-242a-4597-9670-fecb78e6a12b and other threads indicate your problem is your system no longer trust Microsoft certificates.

Comment: [update to 16299.125](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054517) and look what happens

Comment: `c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe c:\Windows\System32\services.msc` worked if executed from cmd as administrator. If I'm going in start menu and search for Services for example I get the errors from screenshots.

Comment: The update to `16299.125` fails at 96% percent and reverts the changes.

Comment: delete all files from C:\Windows\Logs\CBS, open cmd.exe as admin and run  this [DISM command](https://superuser.com/a/693181/174557) to repair corrupted files. If the tool worked and reparied files, try to install the .125 update. if this still doesn't work, copy he complete folder C:\Windows\Logs\CBS to your desktop, zip the folder and share the zip via OneDrive.

Comment: have you generated the newest logs?

Comment: try [latest Update which bumps to 16299.192](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892)

Comment: Thanks for responses.

I couldn't generate them because the last restart crashed my windows with no possibility to restart. Fortunately a reinstall fixed the rights. Now the update worked to 16299.192.I could delete the question since has negative points but while I was investigating I saw that the issue is common.

Comment: post as answer what you did to fix it (with all steps listed if you think this is a common issue and needs an indepth answer)

Comment: **You all are getting it wrong!** OP needs to change permissions so that his user account can 'Read & Execute'! I'll compose an answer when I get back on my workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Windows 10 by keeping my data. There are drawbacks like you need to reinstall some applications. Windows will generate a list with currently installed applications and put it on your desktop `Removed Apps.html`.

Steps to do it (as explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zkvlcnv-UU )

1. Boot in **Advanced Start-Up**

   - Start > Settings > Recovery > Advanced start-up > Restart now
   - More ways to go in Advanced Start-Up: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229
2. After restart in **Advanced Start Up**:

   > Troubleshoot > Reset this PC (Lets you choose to keep or remove your files, then re-installs Windows) > Keep my files
3. Save some files from `c:\Windows.old\` that contains

   ```
   Users
   Program Data
   Program Files
   Program Files (x86)
   ```
4. Copy additional data from old profiles from Users/ to new ones.
5. Reinstall applications found in `Desktop > Removed Apps.html`
6. Cleanup old install (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-remove-windowsold-folder-windows-10)

   > Win+E > This PC > (right click) > Properties > Disk Cleanup > Clean up system files > Previous Windows installation(s) > Ok > Delete Files > Yes

Answer (score -1):

### Problem

`An 'Administrator' has blocked your access to mmc.exe`

This is almost *always* the cause of Malware/Viruses. Before doing the solution, it is recommended to scan your system using your preferred antivirus.

### Solution

1. Find "mmc.exe"; it is located here: "C:\Windows\System32"
2. Right-click the executable then click `Properties` in the drop-down menu. A window should appear.
3. In the window, click the `Security` tab.
4. In this tab, there will be a button called `Advanced`. Click it. A second window should appear.
5. In this window, there will be a hyperlink called `Change` accompanied by a UAC Shield (Blue/Yellow). Click it. 
   A third window should appear.
6. The box accompanied by the text `Enter the object name to select (examples):` should be there. In it, you should write your account's name. For example, if I set up my account with the name: `John Doe`, I would type in 'John'.
7. After you have written your name, click the button named `Ok`. If all has gone well, the third window should disappear. The second window's `Owner` should be your account name.
8. Now click the `Ok` button. The second window should close.
9. Click the `Advanced` button again. The second window should appear again.
10. There will be a button called `Change Permissions` accompanied with the UAC Shield. Click it. The same window should refresh itself.
11. There should be a button called `Add`. Click it. A fourth window should appear.
12. In the fourth window, there should be a hyperlink called `Select a principal`. Click it. A fifth window similar to the third window should appear.
13. Fill the window like you did in Step 6, then click `Ok`. The fifth window should close.
14. The fourth window's checkboxes should no-longer be greyed out. Now check the `Full Control` checkbox. All the boxes should now appear checked.
15. Click the `Ok` button.

There will be a warning reminding you that `The security of your computer will be reduced.` mmc.exe naturally needs administrator permissions to run. You will be able to rectify any viruses easily. Click `OK` on the warning. The fourth window should now close.

16. Now click the `Ok` button for all subsequent windows. (Second, First windows)

Now try runing mmc.exe without administrator permissions.

### Side Notes

mmc.exe is NOT signed on my system either. Mabye it's not meant to be signed?

Comment: What you are doing here is changing the ownership of `mmc.exe` to you.  However, this is a hack, not a fix as members of the Administration group already have read & execute permissions.

Comment: Not really a hack, just reverting default settings. It's possible that a program or someone else has changed the settings of the group `Administrator`.